# How to pass Array from bash and roslaunch to C++ and python scripts as ros params?

Tags: python, c++, bash, parameters, ros

I am new to ROS. I am have created an array in bash script as follows:

```
sen_names=()
q=`jq '.J2.B' ~/camera_gui/sensor_data.json`
w=`jq '.J2.A' ~/camera_gui/sensor_data.json`
sen_names+=("$q")
sen_names+=("$w")
roslaunch image_pub cam_calibration.launch sensor_name:=$sen_names
```

My launch file is as follows:

```
<launch>

  <arg name = "sensor_name" default="[]" />
  <param name="sen_names" type="array" value="$(arg sensor_name)" />

  <param name="size_name" type="str" value="12x8" />
  <param name="square" type="string" value="0.05" />
   
  <node name="im_pub_sub_node" pkg="image_pub" type="im_pub_sub" output="screen"/>
  <node name="cameracalibrator_node" pkg="camera_calibration" type="cameracalibrator.py" output="screen"/>
</launch>
```

My C++ script is:

```
std::vector<std::string>sensor_names;
ros::param::get("/sen_names", sensor_names);
```

My Python script is:

```
sensor_names=[]
sensor_names = rospy.get_param("/sen_names")
```

when I run this, I get error as:

```
RLException: Invalid <param> tag: Unknown type 'array'.
```

1. How to pass this Array from bash as ros param in roslauch to c++ and python scripts?
2. I don't think my C++ script has correct way to get the array into a vector. How to get that into a vector?

Hopefully my python script syntax is correct for getting that array.

Can anyone help me out with this one? Thanks.

Comment: Can anyone please answer this?

Comment: This might help: https://answers.ros.org/question/194592/how-to-read-a-vectorstrings-parameter-from-command-line/?answer=280833#post-id-280833 I think you want to format your bash variables to be a string e.g. my_var="['one', 'two', 'three']" and then it's converted into list automatically. Haven't tested tho